# What is the "content" of a box?

Tags: definition, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If set $A\subseteq X$, let $H^{\alpha}$ be the $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $A$, where $\alpha\in[0,2]$ and $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)$ is the Hausdorff dimension of set $A$.

**Problem:** If the set $A\subseteq[0,1]\times[0,1]$, I want to define a uniform $A$ w.r.t $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)$. For instance,

1. When $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)=0$ and $A$ is finite, then for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, suppose we partition set $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ into $n^2$  squares with side-length $1/n$. If there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that there is only one point from $A$ at the center of each square, we then say $A$ is *uniform* in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.
2. When $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)=2$, for all real $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ and *constant* $\lambda$, if $0\le x_1<x_2\le 1$ and $0\le y_1<y_2\le 1$ with the Lebesgue measure (for sets in the Lebesgue sigma-algebra) of $([x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2])\cap A$ having measure $\lambda(x_2-x_1)(y_2-y_1)$, then set $A$ is *uniform* in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Here is the question I asked:

> What about for $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)\in(0,2)$?

According to @RyanBundey,

> If the set has Hausdorff dimension less than $2$, presumably you would
> want to say the Hausdorff measure of the part of the set $A$ in your
> "box" is some constant multiple of the content of your box.

What does "content" mean? How do we define @RyanBundey's answer mathematically?

Comment: You should link the original question for context. But normally "content" is just another word for the area of the box, $(x_2 - x_1)(y_2-y_1)$.

Comment: @Ted Then does RyanBundey's answer solve my original question? How do we define this mathematically?

Comment: @Ted Just to check, does constant multiple mean the multiple is a natural number?

Comment: I don't have enough context to know, but I would guess "constant multiple" means the same as the $\lambda$ in your original problem.

Comment: "Area" and "volume" are touchy notions in mathematics, and there are many different ways that we try to generalize these notions.  "Content" is one such way.  "Content" basically means the same as "area" or "volume", but it doesn't carry any intrinsic notion of being 2D (area) or 3D (volume) or any other specific dimension.  "Measure" is another similar generalization.